# Unable to start Grunt on OSX. Where does one add Compass?

Tags: ruby, macos, gruntjs, compass

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
    Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.

```
Aborted due to warnings.
```

It is unclear to me where one needs to add ruby and compass? I'm unsure if I even need those two.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby should be installed already on your mac.
Try

```
ruby --version
```

if you are not sure.
If ruby is installed you use

```
sudo gem install compass
```

That should do the trick.